# /Users/username/Library vs /Library installation in macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, mac, macos-sierra

I have two different MacBooks and am trying to install some software I need for use in Xcode on both.

The software doesn't allow you to choose where it's going to go, and I noticed on one machine it is going to:

`/Users/username/Library/SDKs`, while on another machine it's going to the root `/Library/SDKs`.

Can anyone explain what causes that behavior, and how I might be able to force install it elsewhere? I really would like both of these machines to have the same environment.

Comment: What software are you trying to install?

Comment: Are you running the installer from an admin account on both machines? I could imagine an installer checking to see if you're an admin and prompting you for your admin credentials if you are, so it can install in `/Library`. It's a bug not to prompt non-admin users for admin credentials, but I could imagine a buggy installer package making that mistake. If this software package uses macOS's built-in installer, you can use one of the menu commands during the install to show all installation logs (or look in `/var/log/install.log`). Compare installer log messages between machines.

Answer (score -1):

The Library folder, at the root level of your OS X hard drive, is like a public library; it stores items available to everyone who logs into any account on this Mac.

the Library folder  in your users folder containing Preferences, fonts available only to you, and other stuff that you expect to use.

Comment: OP isn't asking what the two folders *are*, he's asking why the same installer is doing two different things on two different machines.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.